# IBM Watson Assistant: Handling X-RateLimit with C# .Net Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I have been following the [IBM API documentation](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/assistant-v1?code=dotnet-standard#listlogs) and [SDK documentation](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/dotnet-standard-sdk/blob/master/src/IBM.Watson.Assistant.v1/IAssistantService.cs) for .NET for IBM Watson Assistant.

I can see in the documentation that there is [rate limiting applied](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/assistant-v1#rate-limiting). So, I am curious on how to obtain

- X-RateLimit-Reset: the time the current timer expires (in UNIX epoch time)
- X-RateLimit-Remaining: the number of requests that remain in the current time window
- X-RateLimit-Limit: the total number of requests allowed within the time window

I have used the API function `assistantService.ListLogs(workspaceId: workspaceId, filter: filter, cursor: Pagination.NextCursor);`, but ran into:

> ServiceResponseException: The API query failed with status code TooManyRequests: Too Many Requests | x-global-transaction-id:  | error: {"error":"Rate limit exceeded","code":429}

Some questions:

1. Is it possible to change these parameters? If yes, how?
2. After 429 code exception, what is the normal time that is needed to wait, in order to send a new request?
3. In C# Using AssistantService doing a call to assistantService.ListLogs(...) How I can obtain the response headers?
4. Is it possible to change the number of  X-RateLimit-Limit?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have experience with .NET, but some with Watson Assistant. The rate limit information is returned in the HTTP response header. You (your code) sends a http request to Watson Assistant and it sends back a http response. In that response you have the header and payload. Check the header.

The rate depends on your [IBM Watson Assistant service plan](https://cloud.ibm.com/catalog/services/watson-assistant). So you can change it by upgrading. The value **X-RateLimit-Reset** is the time when the period for measurement expires. So you can check that to see when new requests are possible again.